# How do you bind a console command to a key?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I would like to bind `pushactoraway 00000014 1` to a key on my keyboard.  Can I create a batch file to do this?

Comment: I'm too busy to give a complete answer right now, but this should be a partial solution: [http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console#Using_Batch_Files_With_the_bat_Command](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console#Using_Batch_Files_With_the_bat_Command)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to bind console commands to keys. If your keyboard has dedicated macro buttons (like the Microsoft Sidewinder) you could easily record the keypresses necessary to make a console macro.

There may also be some software available that turns "unused" keys (like the numpad perhaps) into macros, but I'm unaware of any.

Edit: [this mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/205) allows users to define macros via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and so on. There is no support for console commands yet, but I've requested that feature be added (and it seems fairly easy to implement).

Comment: If this has answered your question satisfactorily, please accept it.