# How to close computer terminal with a hot key?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas, fallout-3

The only possible way to close computer terminals is to click the mouse on the red square button. How can I close it with a keyboard command? It does not need to be a mod, it can be any other way.

I am on PC (but I think other platforms info may help other people too, but I can only check on PC), and so, any mods are welcome too.

Just as information, there is a console command CloseAllMenus (short: cam) that is capable of closing the terminal; though I am not sure how it can help concerning a hot key bind.

Comment: Have you tried pressing the escape key? Try mapping it to close terminal in the pause menu if you can. Tell me if this helped you and I'll make it an answer.

Comment: esc key is to open the main menu and it will open wherever you are, on any other menu it opens!

Comment: This would be really useful during the Brotherhood "Isolate the virus" mission.

Comment: I remember that If you're on an xbox controller (I.E. the Xbox version), to back out of the terminal you would press "B" give me a bit to see what I can find out.

Comment: @Steve V. indeed, I am too used to press `E` key to exit, I wonder if it would be possible to work like that on computer terminals too..

Comment: @AquariusPower what I was meaning by that last comment was that there is a function buried into the PC game because It recognized a Xbox 360 Controller in Windows, finding that command in the command terminal (~) will yield where you should look.

Comment: @Cole Busby, indeed, I read better what you said and I just thought that too!! we may find a precious perl now :), I have no xbox controller tho :>

Comment: @AquariusPower Does tab work to exit the terminal? It supposedly enters into the Pip-Boy and is mapped to the B button in the Xbox edition (I.E. B does the same as tab does in PC)

Comment: @Cole Busby my pipboy button wont close the terminal, also I tried all keys on the keyboard and none worked to close the terminal :(, I wonder if you plug the xbox controller and hit the keyboard pipboy key, if it will work too? :o

Comment: @AquariusPower [Let me know if this helps you and I'll undelete the answer I wrote!](http://www.tweakguides.com/Fallout3_8.html)

Comment: @ColeBusby Though keys can be rebound in the configs, as a rule the configs [don't have access to console commands as binding targets in Bethesda's game engine](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46130/how-do-you-bind-a-console-command-to-a-key). I would be surprised if either Fallout was an exception to this engine limitation.

Comment: @ColeBusby I found no info on the tweakguide regarding "fallout" "close" "computer terminal" on that page or with google :(

Comment: @AquariusPower I meant that link to be for setting up a keybinding but as Seven said there may be a lockout from the console...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mod that will work on PC: 
[Close computer or hacking terminal Hotkey](http://newvegas.nexusmods.com/mods/52181)

Answer (score 0):

[LINUX ONLY]

If you are on linux+wine, this works:

```
xdotool key --delay 250 --window $windowId grave
xdotool type --window $windowId "CloseAllMenus"
xdotool key --delay 250 --window $windowId Return
```

Just put it on a script file and bind a system key to execute that script.

To make it sure what key opens the console (mine is *grave*), use `xev` to get the name of the key.

`$windowId` is the window id you find this way: `xdotool search --name "Default - Wine desktop"` (for this to work you must run wine on a non-windowed mode, the desktop mode)

Non linux answers are welcome too of course; and I still look for a in-game solution tho.